# How can I pass the name of a stringlist as a parameter

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I have written a unit to save multiple stringlists.  Each TStrings item is stored as a record containing the text and an integer value representing the object.  The whole is written to a binary file.  Below is the routine which writes the data.

```
function AddToStream(Stream: TStream; Const pList: TStringList):Boolean;
Var idy: Integer;
    TmpItem: tItemRec;
begin
  TmpItem.pText := pList.ClassName;       // Set up the Header
  TmpItem.pObj := pList.Count * SizeOf(TmpItem);  // Calc the # bytes for Stringlist
  Stream.WriteBuffer(TmpItem, SizeOf(TmpItem));   // Write it to the Stream
  for idy := 0 to plist.Count -1 do begin         // Cycle through StringList
        TmpItem.pText := pList[idy];                  // Get the Text part
        TmpItem.pObj := Integer(pList.Objects[idy]);  // Get the Object part
        Stream.WriteBuffer(TmpItem, SizeOf(TmpItem)); // Write record to stream
  end;
end;
```

The first record writen to the stream is intended to carry a name identifying the stringlist and the number of bytes in the subsequent file.  Obviously in the code above the ClassName returns TStringList, how can I obtain the variable name of the stringlist passed, i.e. MyStringList.

Is it possible to derive it from the standard stringlist passed or do I have to subclass the stringlist and add a VariableName property to the list.

Perhaps I should have shown all of my code. Apart from my original issue I believe I have the code working at least for single TStringLists.  Until I have a decided what to do re the naming issue I haven't tested for multiple Stringlists.  So below is the full unit.

```
unit MultiFileUtils;

interface

Uses
System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Dialogs, system.UITypes;


{This unit enables Multiple stringlist to be saved with objects to a single file
 and reloaded the into the stringlists retaining their originla object value.
 The stringlists you reload to should have classname as the stringlist you saved from
 The data is held in a  binary file, each string list has a aheader which holds
 the ClassName of the stringlist and the length of the file. The text portion
 of each entry in the stringlist should not exceed 255 characters.

 Save functions return true if OK, AllowOverWrite doesn't check file already exists.
 Read function returns true if OK, false if file not found or classname not found in file}

Function SaveLists(Const pLists: Array of TStringList; const pFileName: String; AllowOverwrite: Boolean): Boolean;
Function SaveList(Const pList: TStringList; const pFileName: String; AllowOverwrite: Boolean):Boolean;
Function ReadList(Const pFileName: String; Var pList: TStringList): Boolean;

procedure LoadTestData;
procedure SetUpTests;
procedure TestSave;
procedure TestRead;
Procedure ClearTests;

implementation


Type
  tItemRec = record
    pText: String[255];
    pObj: Integer;
  end;

{$ifDef Debug}
Var StrList1: TStringlist;
    StrList2: TStringlist;
{$EndIf}

function CheckFileExists(pFileName: String):Boolean;
begin
  if FileExists(pFileName) then
    Result := (MessageDlg(pFileName + ' already exists, do you want to overwrite file?',
                          mtConfirmation, [mbYes,mbNo],0) = mrYes);
end;

function AddToStream(Stream: TStream; Const pList: TStringList):Boolean;
Var
  idy: Integer;
  TmpItem: tItemRec;
begin
  TmpItem.pText := pList.ClassName;               // Set up the Header
  TmpItem.pObj := pList.Count * SizeOf(TmpItem);  // Calc the # bytes for Stringlist
  Stream.WriteBuffer(TmpItem, SizeOf(TmpItem));   // Write it to the Stream
  for idy := 0 to plist.Count -1 do begin         // Cycle through StringList
    TmpItem.pText := pList[idy];                  // Get the Text part
    TmpItem.pObj := Integer(pList.Objects[idy]);  // Get the Object part
    Stream.WriteBuffer(TmpItem, SizeOf(TmpItem)); // Write record to stream
  end;
end;

function SaveLists(Const pLists: Array of TStringList; Const pFileName: String;
                   AllowOverwrite: Boolean): Boolean;
Var
  idx: Integer;
  Stream: TStream;
begin
  if AllowOverwrite then
    Result := true
  else
    Result := CheckFileExists(pFileName);
  if Result then begin
    Stream := TFileStream.Create(pFileName, fmCreate); // Set up a fileStream
    try
      for idx := 0 to Length(plists) do           // Loop through array of stringlists
        AddToStream(Stream, pLists[idx]);         // Add each Stringlist
    finally
      Stream.Free;                                // Write to disk and free Stream
    end;
  end;
end;

function SaveList(Const pList: TStringList; const pFileName: String;
                  AllowOverwrite: Boolean): Boolean;
Var
  idx: Integer;
  Stream: TStream;
begin
  If AllowOverwrite then
    result := true
  else
    Result := CheckFileExists(pFileName);
  if Result then begin
    Stream := TFileStream.Create(pFileName, fmCreate); // Set up filestream
    try
      AddToStream(Stream, pList);                 // Add Stringlist to stream
    finally
      Stream.Free;                                // Write to disk and free Stream
    end;
  end;
end;

function ReadList(Const pFileName: String; var pList: TStringList): Boolean;
Var idx: Integer;
  Stream: TStream;
  TmpItem: tItemRec;

  Function NotEos: Boolean;
  begin
    Result := Stream.Position < Stream.Size;
  end;

begin
  Result := false;
  if FileExists(pFileName) then begin
    Stream := TFileStream.Create(pFileName, fmOpenRead);
    Stream.Seek(0, soBeginning);
    while NotEos do begin
      if Stream.Read(TmpItem, SizeOf(TmpItem)) = SizeOf(TmpItem) then  // Read Header
        if TmpItem.pText = pList.ClassName then begin
          Result := True;                         // Found header so file looks OK
          idx := TmpItem.pObj;                    // Get the byte count
          while (idx > 0) And NotEos do begin
            Stream.ReadBuffer(TmpItem, SizeOf(TmpItem));
            pList.AddObject(Trim(TmpItem.pText), Pointer(TmpItem.pObj));
            Dec(idx);
          end;
          break;
        end;
    end;
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;

{$ifDef Debug}
Procedure LoadTestData;
Var i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to 20 do begin
    StrList1.AddObject('StrLst1 Data' + IntToStr(i), Pointer(i+1000));
    StrList2.AddObject('StrLst2 Data' + IntToStr(i), pointer(i+2000));
  end;
end;

procedure SetUpTests;
begin
  StrList1 := TStringList.Create;
  StrList2 := TStringList.Create;
  LoadTestData;
end;

Procedure TestSave;
begin
  SaveList(StrList1, 'MyTestFile.dat', true);
end;

Procedure TestRead;
begin
  StrList1.Clear;
  ReadList('MyTestFile.dat', StrList1);
end;

procedure ClearTests;
begin
  StrList1.Free;
  StrList2.Free;
end;
{$endif}

end.
```

Comment: Show `tItemRec` definition. Compiled exe doesn't contain variable names. Please explain, how are you going to use name information during retrieving?

Comment: Variable names are not compiled, the compiler doesn't need them in the executable code. They are for humans.

Comment: BTW the second paragraph may imply you think you are writing the class name to the stream. You are not, the stream contains addresses of the strings and objects.

Comment: A short string is different ofcourse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A string list instance does not have a name. Variable names cannot be retrieved programmatically, and even if they could the variable at the call site would be lost by the time you were inside the function. What you are attempting to do is not possible.

In my view the cleanest thing to do is to pass an extra argument to your function containing the name. You could equally use a derived class that adds a name but that would constrain consumers of this code to use that derived class.

Looking at your code that writes the string list, it is very broken. You appear to be writing memory addresses rather than the content of the memory. But that's a different problem.

Comment: I understand the question asking about the name of a variable that is assigned an instance, as opposed to a possible name that the object instance has. I may be wrong though.

Comment: @sertac you think the asker wants a string with the value `pList`?

Comment: Either that, or what he calls the list in the call site. That's how I understood it.

Comment: @Sertac It's somewhat moot wondering which of these impossible tasks the asker is look to perform though.... Whichever it is, it can't be done.

Comment: Indeed. The way I understand it makes even less sense.

Comment: @sertac You are probably right though reading it again. I got sidetracked by the part asking about a property of the list. The code in the question has so many problems that I think the asker has a lot of adjustment to do before being able to make progress.